# Merge two arrays into single arrays in php laravel and displaying in blade

Tags: php, laravel

I want to filter the datas according to colleges and universities and my query is

```html
$exams = Exam::where('status', 1);
        if ($request->filled('universities')) {
            $exams = $exams->whereIn('university_id', $request->universities);  //data 1st
        }
        if ($request->filled('colleges')) {
            $exams = $exams->whereIn('college_id', $request->colleges); //data 2nd
        }
        $exams = $exams->get();
```

And my form is

```html
<form action="">
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    @foreach($universities as $university)
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a href="#">
                <label>
                    <input name='universities[]' onchange="searchExam();"
                           class="mr-2" type="checkbox"
                           value='{{$university->id}}'/>
                    {{$university->name}}
                </label>
            </a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    @foreach($colleges as $college)
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a href="#">
                <label>
                    <input onchange="searchExam();" name='colleges[]'
                           class="mr-2" type="checkbox"
                           value='{{$college->id}}'/>
                    {{$college->name}}
                </label>
            </a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
</form>
```

My problem is I am getting data for only either universities or colleges but what I want is if colleges and universities options are checked, I want to get data for both colleges and universities. How can I merge these two datas into single array?

Comment: so you want this to be an `OR` thing, where it is by college or by universities? .. you need to elaborate on this mroe

Comment: I want data for both universities and colleges

Comment: im guessing you need an `OR` then because right now you have an `AND` ... you will need to adjust how you do this and group these 2 conditions

Comment: I am filtering data based on colleges and universities section checked by user

Comment: Please  also look into my form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to group the wheres for the college or university. You can try something like this:

```
$exams = Exam::where('status', 1);

if ($request->has('universities', 'colleges')) {
    $exams->where(function ($q) use ($request) {
        if ($request->input('universities')) {
            $q->orWhereIn('university_id', (array) $request->input('universities'));
        }

        if ($request->input('colleges')) {
            $q->orWhereIn('college_id', (array) $request->input('colleges'));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able use `orWhereIn` eloquent function for this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/f802e8134bc898871cd02398621745cee45739ef/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L974

```php
Exam::where('status', 1)
      ->orWhereIn('university_id', $request->universities ?? false)
      ->orWhereIn('college_id', $request->colleges ?? false)
      ->get();
```

This should produce (assuming that table name is `exams`) something like:

```
"select * from `exams` where `status` = ? and (`university_id` IN ? or `college_id` IN ?)"
```

If that doesn't work with your PHP version, you could try adding conditional clauses ( https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#conditional-clauses)

```php
Exam::where('status', 1)
      ->when($request->universities, function ($query) use ($request) {
          return $query->whereIn('university_id', $request->universities);
      })
      ->when($request->colleges, function ($query) use ($request) {
          return $query->whereIn('college_id', $request->colleges);
      })
      ->get();
```

Comment: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, null given. I got this

Comment: Again same error . Aslo I getting this when hovering on ?? Coalesce operator is available in PHP 7 only.

Comment: Oh, which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP 7.3.12 and in my composer "php": "^7.3|^8.0",

Comment: Your first code won't work because the `WHERE ... IN` clause is always added to the query even when it's not needed. Second code is a good answer!

Comment: return $query->whereIn('university_id', $request->universities); I this line I am getting Trying to get properties universities of non-object